# Wash chinese calligraphy brush outside?

Tags: brush, calligraphy

Do any of you have any tips about how can I wash my chinese calligraphy brushes when I am not at home ?

Regards

Comment: Have you tried [Googling it](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=wash+chinese+calligraphy+brush)?  Your question isn't really a good fit for this site

Comment: More info about what questions _are_ a good fit can be found [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with maintenance, not design

Answer (score 0):

Since this didn't close yet, and I actually have a decent answer, I'm just gonna post..

When I did fine art outside/away from my studio, I used Turpenoid Natural, or Odorless Turpentine. It's basically a paint, pigment or ink thinner(mineral spirit). If you aren't going to be switching colors then you could get away with having a damp rag. But if you plan to chance colors while painting, get a baby food jar and fill it half way, bring a dry rag.

It's a little better than water since it thins the pigment in the brush and helps clean it better. It's typically used in oil painting, so I don't believe you'll have any problem thinning or cleaning (I'm assuming india ink) from your brush.

Comment: Don't use turpentine on brushes for water-based media. It is not miscible with water and leaves a residue which repels water.

Comment: The reason I suggested turpentine was because when I used india ink, It was done dry brush.